# React testing library setting window=undefined

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, window, react-testing-library

I am testing a react hook which gets the window-dimensions from window.innerheight and window.innerwidth. It uses the following code to handle server side rendering:

```
...

typeof window=="undefined" ? {width: 1024, height: 768} : functionToGetDimensions()

...
```

When trying to make tests for this line in react-testing-library i need to delete the window object:

```
...

const TestComponent = ({ }) => {
    const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
    return (
        <div>
            <p data-testid="width">{width}</p>
            <p data-testid="height">{height}</p>
        </div>)
}


describe('when window is undefined', () => {
    //@ts-ignore
    
    const testWidth = 1000;
    const testHeight = 800;

    const fallbackWidth = 1024; // when useWindowdimensions detects window = undefined
    const { window } = global;
    
beforeAll(() => {
      // @ts-ignore
      delete global.window;
    });
    afterAll(() => {
      global.window = window;
    }); 

    
    it('runs without error', () => {
        render(<TestComponent />)        
        expect(screen.queryByTestId("height")).toHaveTextContent(fallbackWidth );
    });
});
```

I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I've tried using node as test enviroment, but then document is not defined, and render does not work.

Comment: Test the hook with react-hooks-testing-library and not DOM, for starters. Making window undefined and using browser API at the same time won't work, obviously.

Comment: react-hooks-testing-library seems to have the same problem. It seems to require window and document to work.

Comment: Why you are using `node` as  test environment rather than `jsdom`